# Writing first $5$ terms of recurrence relation

Tags: recursion

How do I write the first $5$ terms for this recurrence relation?

$$S_0=2\\
S_n=S_{n-1}^2 +S_{n-2}^2+\ldots+S_0^2$$

Since I can't substitute $S_0$ directly?

Comment: Write $S_1$. (Then $S_2$. Then $S_3$. Then $S_4$...)

Comment: How do I find S2 S3 and S4?

Comment: Once you've written $S_1$, write $S_2$. (Then $S_3$. Then $S_4$...)

Answer (score 1):

What you are meant to do is:
$$S_0 = 2\\
S_1 = S_0^2 = 2^2 = 4 \\
S_2 = S_1^2+S_0^2 = 4^2+2^2 = 20 \\
S_3 = S_2^2+S_1^2+S_0^2 = 400 + 16 + 4 = 420
$$
And so forth (two more lines) until you have $S_5$..